# Why did I just get the close privilege?

Tags: support, bug, privileges

Someone just upvoted one of my questions, and I got a notification. At the same time (likely due to that action) I also got a notification that I was awarded the close/reopen voting privilege.

[image: screenshot of notification]

That's all great, except for the [close vote privilege page](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) says that it is awarded at 3,000 points of reputation, and I have 3,502. (It's listed at 3,000 at the regular [privileges page](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) as well.)

Is the page wrong? Or did something glitch out with the mechanism that decides what privileges you should be awarded?

Comment: Have you been able to Vote to Close?  I'm also at ~3500 and have been able to VTC since I hit 3000 a couple months ago

Comment: I don't recall seeing the close link prior to yesterday (though I wasn't actually looking for it intentionally.)

Comment: I wonder if there is some kind of lag happening somehow.  My [Travel Meta reputation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZfjR.png), for example, is still under 3k (don't know why).

Comment: @Midavalo when I go to your meta profile it's at 3.5k and matches your main rep. Possibly the drop down is showing cached values or something?